# LINQ Contains using projection

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>{
    new Employee {ID = 101, FirstName = "Mark", AnnualSalary = 60000},
    new Employee {ID = 102, FirstName = "Mary", AnnualSalary = 35000},
    new Employee {ID = 103, FirstName = "John", AnnualSalary = 30000}
};

var result5 = listEmployees.Select(x => new {x.ID, x.FirstName})
    .Contains(new Employee {ID = 101, FirstName "Mark"});
Response.Write(result5 + "<br/>");
```

How can I compare if employee ID 101 and FirstName "Mark" exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to find out if a list contains an item matching your criteria:

```
Employee employee = listEmployees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == 101 && e.FirstName.Equals("Mark"));

if(employee != null) //exists
{
    //can take action on employee
}
```

or, if you want a boolean response (like Contains):

```
boolean exists = listEmployees.Any(e => e.ID == 101 && e.FirstName == "Mark");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
listEmployees.Any(employee => employee.FirstName.Equals("Mark") && employee.ID == 101)
```

This would return true if any objects in the list have the FirstName "Mark" and ID 101. It could be generalized if you need to use it in a method.

Answer (score 1):

The item you pass to `Contains` needs to match the type of the items in the sequence, in this case, the particular anonymous type, rather than being of some other type.  If you provide an object of an anonymous type (Using the same fields of the same type and name), rather than an `Employee`, it will compile and run just fine.

Comment: Wouldn't the anonymous type need an overridden `Equals` method for `Contains` to properly match two separate but identical instances?  (I may have misunderstood the question or your answer.  If so, sorry--)

Comment: @adv12 Yes, it would, and it does.

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize that was a built-in feature of anonymous types.  I'll do some more reading.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for checking that a item with a particular condition is in list or not

```
bool exists = listEmployees.Exists(x=> x.ID == 101 && x.FirstName=="Mark");
```